# How to parse values distributed across an array with Aeson?

Tags: haskell, aeson

I have an json value of:

```
{
  "name": "xyz1",
  "extra": [
    {
      "this_string_A": "Hello"
    },
    {
      "this_string_B": "World"
    }
  ]
}
```

And a data type of:

```
data Abc = Abc
  { name :: String 
  , a :: Maybe String
  , b :: Maybe String
  } deriving (Generic, Show)
```

In the above case I would want it to parse with a result of `Abc "xyz1" (Just "Hello") (Just "World")`.

I can't figure out how to conditionally parse the values within `extra` (which is a JSON **array**) within the aeson `Parser` context. How can I get `extra[0].this_string_a` for example? I

**What I tried:**

I thought I could create my own `Parser (Maybe String)` function but ran into confusing errors:

```
instance FromJSON Abc where
     parseJSON = withObject "Abc" $ \v -> Abc
         <$> v .: "name"
         <*> myParse v
         <*> myParse v

myParse :: Object -> Parser (Maybe String)
myParse x =  withArray "extra" myParse2 (x)

myParse2 :: Array -> Parser (Maybe String)
myParse2 = undefined
```

typecheck fails with:

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘unordered-containers-0.2.10.0:Data.HashMap.Base.HashMap
                             text-1.2.3.1:Data.Text.Internal.Text Value’
                     with ‘Value’
      Expected type: Value
        Actual type: Object
    • In the third argument of ‘withArray’, namely ‘(x)’
```

And if I replace `x` with `Object x` then I get parse error of:

```
Left "Error in $: parsing extra failed, expected Array, but encountered Object"
```

---

Full example (run `test` function to test):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Example where

import GHC.Generics
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.Types

data Abc = Abc
  { name :: String 
  , a :: Maybe String
  , b :: Maybe String
  } deriving (Generic, Show)

instance FromJSON Abc where
     parseJSON = withObject "Abc" $ \v -> Abc
         <$> v .: "name"
         <*> (v.: "extra") -- find where object has key of this_string_a ??
         <*> (v.: "extra") -- find where object has key of this_string_b ??

test :: Either String Abc
test = eitherDecode exampleJson

exampleJson = "{ \"name\": \"xyz1\", \"extra\": [ { \"this_string_A\": \"Hello\" }, { \"this_string_B\": \"World\" } ] }"
```

Comment: Is it an option to instead model `extra` as a sum type instead of two `Maybe` values?

Comment: Two `Maybe` values seem odd, because that design allows for four states, including that both are `Nothing` and both are `Just`.

Comment: Could you give a couple other input samples?   It's not clear ( to me at least ) what kind of variation you might have in the json.   For example,  is `extra` always present?  Does `extra` always contain two elements?  Do the elements of `extra` always have exactly one key/value pair?   Are the keys always either `this_string_A` or `this_string_B`  or might something else be encountered?

Comment: I'm not worried about variations. If I could just get it to work with the provided input that that would be sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `withXXX` "helpers" make everything kind of awkward, but here goes.

The Aeson `Parser` type is misnamed, and this causes confusion.
The idea with Aeson `Parser` objects is that they represent a monadic parse *result*.  (This is different from the `Parser` objects you find in Parsec, etc., which represent actual monadic parsers.)  So, you should think of a `Parser a` as isomorphic to an `Either ParseError a` -- a monadic result with the possibility of failure.

These parse results are usually combined applicatively.  So if you have a parser like:

```
data Xyz = Xyz { x :: String, y :: String }
instance FromJSON Xyz where
  parseJSON = withObject "Xyz" $ \v ->
    Xyz <$> v .: "x" <*> v .: "y"
```

the parse results `v .: "x"` and `v .: "y"` have type `Parser String` which is really like `Either ParseError a`, and the last line of that instance is the usual method of combining successful and unsuccessful results in an applicative manner, along the lines of:

```
Xyz <$> Right "value_x" <*> Left "while parsing Xyz: key y was missing"
```

Now, the function `parseJSON` has type `Value -> Parser a`.  This is what should properly be called a **parser**, but to avoid confusion, let's call it a "parse function".  A parse function takes a JSON representation (a `Value`, or an `Object` or some other JSON thingy) and returns a parse result.  The `withXXX` family of functions are used to adapt parse functions between JSON thingies.  If you have a parse function that expects an `Object`, like:

```
\v -> Xyz <$> v .: "x" <*> v .: "y"   :: Object -> Parser Xyz
```

and you want to adapt it to `parseJSON :: Value -> Parser Xyz`, you use `withObject "str" :: (Object -> Parser Xyz) -> (Value -> Parser Xyz)` to do it.

Getting back to your problem, if you'd like to write a core parser that looks like:

```
\v -> Abc <$> v .: "name" <*> extra .:? "this_string_A"
                          <*> extra .:? "this_string_B"
```

you want `extra` to be an `Object`, and you want to extract it monadically from the overall JSON object `v :: Object`, using appropriate `withXXX` helpers to adapt parse functions from one input JSON thingy type to another.  So, let's write a monadic function (a parse function, in fact) to do that:

```
getExtra :: Object -> Parser Object
getExtra v = do
```

First, we monadically extract the optional "extra" component from `v`.  We use the conditional form here, so `mextra :: Maybe Value`.

```
  mextra <- v .:? "extra"
```

Second, let's monadically create our final `Object` out of "mextra".  This will be the JSON `Object` whose keys are `"this_string_A"` and `"this_string_B"` with the array layer removed.  Note the type of this case expression will be `Parser Object`, a parse result of type `Object = HashMap key value`.  For the `Just` case, we have a `Value` that we expect to be an array, so let's use the `withArray` helper to ensure that.  Note that the `withArray "str"` helper function takes our *parse function* of type `\arr -> do ... :: Array -> Parser Object` and adapts it to `Value -> Parser Object` so it can be applied to `vv :: Value`.

```
  case mextra of
    Just vv -> vv & withArray "Abc.extra" (\arr -> do
```

Now, `arr` is an `Array = Vector Value`.  We hope it's an array of `Object`s.  Let's pull the `Value`s out as a list:

```
      let vallst = toList arr
```

and then monadically traverse the list with the help of `withObject` to ensure they're all `Object`s as expected.  Note the use of `pure` here, since we want to extract the `Object`s as-is without any additional processing:

```
      objlst <- traverse (withObject "Abc.extra[..]" pure) vallst
```

Now, we have an `objlst :: [Object]`.  They're a set of singleton hashmaps with disjoint keys, and the `Object` / hashmap we want is their union, so let's return that.  The parenthesis here ends the `withArray` expression that's being applied to `vv`:

```
      return $ HashMap.unions objlst)
```

For the `Nothing` case ("extra" not found), we merely return an empty hashmap:

```
    Nothing -> return HashMap.empty
```

The full function looks like this:

```
getExtra :: Object -> Parser Object
getExtra v = do
  mextra <- v .:? "extra"
  case mextra of
    Just vv -> vv & withArray "Abc.extra" (\arr -> do
      let vallst = toList arr
      objlst <- traverse (withObject "Abc.extra[..]" pure) vallst
      return $ HashMap.unions objlst)
    Nothing -> return HashMap.empty
```

and you use it in your parser instance like so:

```
instance FromJSON Abc where
  parseJSON =
   withObject "Abc" $ \v -> do
    extra <- getExtra v
    Abc <$> v .: "name" <*> extra .:? "this_string_A" <*> extra .:? "this_string_B"
```

With a test case:

```
example :: BL.ByteString
example = "{\"name\": \"xyz1\", \"extra\": [{\"this_string_A\": \"Hello\"}, {\"this_string_B\": \"World\"}]}"

main = print (eitherDecode example :: Either String Abc)
```

it works like so:

```
λ> main
Right (Abc {name = "xyz1", a = Just "Hello", b = Just "World"})
```

The full code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Aeson (eitherDecode, FromJSON, Object, parseJSON, withArray, withObject, (.:), (.:?))
import Data.Aeson.Types (Parser)
import GHC.Generics (Generic)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL (ByteString)
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as HashMap (empty, unions)
import Data.Function ((&))
import Data.Foldable (toList)

data Abc = Abc
  { name :: String
  , a :: Maybe String
  , b :: Maybe String
  } deriving (Generic, Show)

instance FromJSON Abc where
  parseJSON =
   withObject "Abc" $ \v -> do
    extra <- getExtra v
    Abc <$> v .: "name" <*> extra .:? "this_string_A" <*> extra .:? "this_string_B"

getExtra :: Object -> Parser Object
getExtra v = do
  mextra <- v .:? "extra"
  case mextra of
    Just vv -> vv & withArray "Abc.extra" (\arr -> do
      let vallst = toList arr
      objlst <- traverse (withObject "Abc.extra[..]" pure) vallst
      return $ HashMap.unions objlst)
    Nothing -> return HashMap.empty

example :: BL.ByteString
example = "{\"name\": \"xyz1\", \"extra\": [{\"this_string_A\": \"Hello\"}, {\"this_string_B\": \"World\"}]}"

main = print (eitherDecode example :: Either String Abc)
```